# Use different classes in one module

Tags: python, odoo

how can i define two different view in one module on Odoo (Openerp)?

My python code:

```
from openerp.osv import osv, fields

class menu(osv.Model):
    _name = "menu"
    _description = "Menu"
    _columns = {
        ...
    }

class ordini(osv.Model):
    _name = "ordini"
    _description = "Ordini"
    _columns = {
                ...
    }
```

I have 2 classes, i want to use these in my view:

```
    <record id="view_menu_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">menu.form</field>
        <field name="model">menu</field>
   ...
    </record>

    <record id="view_ordini_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">ordini.form</field>
        <field name="model">ordini</field>
        ...
    </record>
```

I have an error when I install the module:

> ```
> Error details:
> ```
>
> Model not found: ordini

Comment: This generally shouldn't be a problem, so I think there must be a different issue at play.

Comment: Thanks. I have defined the same class again and it works! :)